# How to write a vector of ofstreams into files

Tags: c++

I am having some strange issues while I write an `std::vector` of `ofstreams` into text files. I have created an `std::vector` of length 10000 and when I write them, I only get 7200 files instead of 10000 files. I am not sure what is going on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int V = 10000;
    std::vector<std::ofstream> vec_of_streams;
    vec_of_streams.reserve(V);

    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i){
      std::string name = "file_" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
      vec_of_streams.push_back(std::move(std::ofstream{ name }));
    }

    for (int i =0; i < V; ++i)
    {
        vec_of_streams[i] << "temporary text number: " << i << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using MacOS with Catalina.

Based on the comments, I changed as follows. Could anyone let me know if this can be made more efficient?

```
int main()
{
    int V = 10000;

    std::vector<std::string> file_names_vector;
    file_names_vector.resize(V);

    for (auto i = 0; i < V; ++i){
      std::string name = "file_" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
      file_names_vector[i] = name;
    }


    for (int i =0; i < V; ++i)
    {
        std::ofstream file{file_names_vector[i]};
        file << "temporary text number: " << i << "\n";
        file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding some error checking to your code? 10k files open all at once  is a lot and it's possible that at a point opening the file is failing.

Comment: What is your operating system? OT: Your use of `std::move` has no effect. `std::ofstream{name}` is rvalue by itself.

Comment: Operating systems usually have a limit to how many file handles a process can have open at once. Mine is 1024, for instance.

Comment: Relevant: [Is there a limiltation of simultaneous filestreams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17473182/580083)

Comment: On my machine in Windows 10 the first  509 open, the rest fail.

Comment: Please include information on your OS in the question. The code itself looks fine

Comment: Why you cannot use a `std::vector<std::string>` (or something similar) to remember the names of files to write to? Then, you need only one file stream in the loop to open a file, write to it, and close it again. That's probably more OS friendly. 10000 concurrently open streams are really a lot.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks! I did what you suggested and added the code above.