# How to debug random std::ofstream failure?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following function to create an `std::ofstream`. It determines the exact file name, creates the stream and if the file is new, writes a header before returning the stream.

```
auto open(const std::filesystem::path& targetFolder) -> std::ofstream {
    auto path = targetFolder / blablablaSomeStuff;
    std::ofstream os(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    if (not os)
        throw std::runtime_error(fmt::format("Cannot append to file {}: {}",
                                             path.string(), strerror(errno)));
    os.exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit | std::ofstream::badbit);

    // add headers to new files
    if (os.tellp() == 0) {
        ...   // write header to file
    }

    return os;
}
```

The stream is then used from the call site. I am unpredictably getting I/O errors, either directly from my own throw:

`Cannot append to file /path1/path2/filename.csv: Bad file descriptor`

Or later an exception when using the stream:

`exception.code().message()`: `iostream error`

`strerror(errno)`: `Bad file descriptor`

I should maybe also mention that I am constantly opening and closing files, only ever writing one line, with thousands of files. That's maybe uncommon, but not illegal, I would say.

1. Is there anything wrong with how I open the file?
2. Is it okay to return the stream like that? Using C++ 17.
3. The error messages are useless. How can I debug the issue further?

Comment: You cannot use `errno` with `ofstream`. Plus the way you are calling `strerror`, memory allocation functions like `path.string()` can set it to a new value.

Comment: You might have a file descriptor leak, and ran out of file descriptors.

Comment: Maybe related [is-there-a-limiltation-of-simultaneous-filestreams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473182/is-there-a-limiltation-of-simultaneous-filestreams)

Comment: @Jarod42: Interesting point. But would it still apply if I told you that I close each and every stream before opening the new one?

Comment: @StaceyGirl Thank you, do you have any idea how to get a good error-related system message?

Comment: @MadMike Unfortunately there is no way. I try to not use `fstream` for this and many other reasons - it is too broken. On Linux you can use tools like `strace` to check what actually happened underneath.

Comment: I don't know, you might look at number of opened fstream when you encounter an error. maybe there is some delay before being really available...

Comment: Other random problems: Filesystem could be full; There could be too many files in the directory; The filename could be too long; etc.